# Firebase and crossroads user profile

Tags: javascript, firebase, crossroadsjs

how can I make a router system with crossroads.js where if I go to for example this URL: localhost/user/{{username}} then get the details of that user there's entered in the URL with firebase.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. You may want to read up on http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask clear, concise questions that includes the important parts of your code that are causing you trouble. SO is not a free code writing service, you'll have to make an effort yourself, and then we can have a look to see where you may need pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

get user detail once :

```
var database = firebase.database();

    var route1 = crossroads.addRoute('/user/{username}', function(id){
      firebase.database().ref('/user/' + id).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      var username = snapshot.val().username;
      // ...
        });
    });
```